# Weird screen behavior in remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

After working fine for months, my remote desktop suddenly started behaving weird during established connection. I don't really know how to describe it, the screen kind of shifts with the cursor and even in full screen mode it doesn't fit the actual screen (it did before it started behaving weird). Also, the cursor of the remote computer is now visible, which wasn't before, and its response lags considerably behind the cursor of the local computer. Here is a gif, showing the issue
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQhn.gif)

It is very possible that I accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcut, changing some settings, but I'm unable to find any solutions or figure it out myself. It is extremely annoying. I connect from a Windows 10 machine to a Linux Ubuntu machine, using Remote Desktop Connection available in Windows.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting a lower resolution in the remote session? My guess is that will fix it for you.

Comment: I did, nothing helped. It is weird that when the session starts it looks ok, but as soon as I enter the remote desktop window with the cursor, it immediately zooms in and destroys the resolution.